# CrudRepository is null after initializing the application in Spring

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, repository, autowired

This is part of mongo-config.xml:

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.padmenu.web.repositories"
    mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate" query-lookup-strategy="create-if-not-       found">
    <mongo:repository id="userRepository" />
    <mongo:repository id="categoryRepository" />
</mongo:repositories>
```

and inside applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.padmenu" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<import resource="mongo-config.xml" />
```

My CategoryRepository is

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long> {

}
```

My CategoryBean is

```
public class CategoryBean implements Serializable {

@Autowired
CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
```

In the PostConstruct of the CategoryBean

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    selectedCategory = new Category();
    categoryList = (List<Category>) categoryRepository.findAll();
    deleteCategoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();
    userLocaleList = new ArrayList<Locale>();
    userLocaleList.add(new Locale("tr"));
    userLocaleList.add(new Locale("en"));
    isForUpdate = false;
}
```

Here categoryRepository is null. What is the reason? Why auto wiring is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 
@Controller to public class CategoryBean implements Serializable solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am glad you got it working.

Just in case it help, I did a spring/mongodb example a few months ago. Details of my example are here:

http://www.littlelostmanuals.com/2011/09/spring-mongodb-type-safe-queries.html

Code at https://github.com/cjharris5/spring-mongodb-querydsl